# How to check unclosed tags stored in column values in oracle sql

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

I have a table in which column value for one of the row is like

"SERIS is developing a high-quality sky-imaging system for solar resource assessment and forecasting. One of the key features concerns irradiance measurements. First tests are promising, with a mean absolute error close to 50 W/m<sup>2</sup>."

Here you can tag /sup> is incomplete as it does not have starting tag

I want to find in my table via sql query how many columns are there which is having unclosed tag

Any solutions

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find out if XML is valid then use an XML parser.

You can use a function to test parsing the XML and catch any exceptions and then count the invalid rows:

```
WITH FUNCTION is_valid_xml(data CLOB) RETURN NUMBER
     IS
       v_xml XMLTYPE;
     BEGIN
       v_xml := XMLTYPE('<root>' || data || '</root>');
       RETURN 1;
     EXCEPTION
       WHEN OTHERS THEN
         RETURN 0;
     END;
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM   table_name
WHERE  is_valid_xml(column_name) = 0;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (column_name) AS
SELECT EMPTY_CLOB() || '<sup>2</sup>' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT EMPTY_CLOB() || '<sup>2/sup>' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| COUNT(*) |
| --- |
| 1 |

You can also create a stored function (rather than declaring it inline to the query) using:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION is_valid_xml(data CLOB) RETURN NUMBER
IS
  v_xml XMLTYPE;
BEGIN
  v_xml := XMLTYPE('<root>' || data || '</root>');
  RETURN 1;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    RETURN 0;
END;
/
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/YXuAzLgk)

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer 
but my requirment is not to check if the xml is valid

the thing is as per example I want to find the columns values which is having tags that have unclosed tags

Comment: @Arun Practically, it is the same. Imagine you have the XML `<A><B></A></B>` you can ask if `A` and `B` have matching closing tags (and you will probably get the wrong answer of, yes, every `A` and every `B` has a closing tag) or you can ask if it is valid XML and the answer is, no, it is not as the `A` and `B` closing tags are in the wrong order so `A` gets closed but `B` does not and then there is a spurious `B` closing tag. If you want to parse XML properly then you **NEED** to use an XML parser (don't try [doing it with regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/1509264)).